# How do I obtain a cross product with multiple tables?

Tags: racket

I am trying to obtain a cross product between two lists. I can see that the problem is that it's trying to append `(CP2 T1 T2)` with `(CP2 T1 T3)`. I have thought of other ways, such as `(CP2 (CP2 T1 T2) ...)`, but again, the ellipses just expand into an undesired output.

```
(define-syntax CP
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((CP T1 T2 ...)
     (append (CP2 T1 T2) ...)
       )
    )
  )

(define (CP2 T1 T2)
  (foldr append '() (map (λ(x)
                           (map (λ(y) (append x y)) T2))
                         T1))
  )
```

Is it not possible doing it this way at all?

Thank you.

Comment: Consider the built-in [`cartesian-product`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._cartesian-product%29%29) function.

Comment: I... I can't believe that. I spent so much time working on that. Thanks. :(

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with one of the for loops also ( http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html ):

```
(define (myproduct l1 l2)
  (for*/list ((i l1)(j l2))
    (list i j)))

(myproduct '(1 2 3) '(a b c))
```

Ouput:

```
'((1 a) (1 b) (1 c) (2 a) (2 b) (2 c) (3 a) (3 b) (3 c))
```